# Add pound sign to my formula in Excel

Tags: excel, formula

I have a Column of positive numbers I have used this formula `=SUMIF(K8:K8,">0")` this is working fine, but how do i add a pound sign to the positive numbers? I have tried going to column and changing it to currency but this then displays £0.00 which is what i don't want.
I'm hoping there is a way of adding it into the formula `=SUMIF(K8:K8,">0"="£")` or something like that ?

Comment: You want the cell/range `K8:K8` to get the `£` or the result of the `SUMIF`? And how do you want the result to look like exactly? Is the 'range' always one cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

`=SUMIF(K8:K8,">0")&"£"`

Or rather you'd want to apply CUSTOM number formatting to your cell:

`# ##0.00£`